# loading a csv file which is on local system in to Mysql DB which is on remote webserver

Tags: mysql, csv, import, local

I have a csv file created daily by my local machine and stored locally in c:\logs\ the file name is import.csv.

I would like to be able to import this onto my websites MYSQL server, into a database called Spottingdb into a table called spotting.

Can anyone help point me in the correct direction, I have tried the following which is run from a batch file in the c:\logs directory -

```
mysqlimport --local --host=www.planespotterslog.co.uk --user=root --password --fields-terminated-by=',' --fields-optionally-enclosed-by='"' Spottingdb spotting import.csv
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your instruction could do the job if port 3306 used by mysql is open on your server. Which is quite dangerous. If you open such port, don't allow root access, create another mysql account which can only insert in target table and specify client ip address in account.

To avoid opening port 3306 on your server I would highly recommend to use a web form to import file into database, for example in php. then web site can control user access. web form processes file and imports it into database.

It is not very difficult to import a csv file in php. you can also use existing libraries like PHPExcel https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel or  excel reader https://github.com/nuovo/spreadsheet-reader that implement already reading excel or csv files

popular PHPMyAdmin allows you to import CSV files in your remote MYSQL database as well. with that, you don't need to develop anything in PHP, just to install PHPMyAdmin, if it is not already on your server.

Again, as you're intending to open your database over Internet in some way, don't neglect security, for example, I can see about 100 attempts per day  to search  phpmyadmin on my web server, despite it is not even installed on my web server !